# has_many association with conditions on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have this models: `Store` and `Address`.

The second model `Address` I'm using this with other models and has some custom fields inside for different models.

Yes like polymorphic but without the `varchar` field for Class, I'm using an integer. (optimization stuff)

now on my `Store` model the association in set like this:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :conditions => ['parent_kind = ?', 2]
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

Now in my controller I do:

`@store.addresses.build`

And I can use `f.fields_for :addresses...` inside the form.

The problem comes out when I submit the form and the data is saved to the database.

The record in the `stores` table is saved, the record in `addresses` is saved with the `parent_id` of the store in place, but the `parent_kind` is in `0` which is the default value for that attribute on MySQL.

My Quick fix was this:

```
@store = Store.new(params[:store])
    @store.addresses[0].parent_kind = 2
    if @store.save
    ....
```

But I know there must be another way.

Anny suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using a hidden field in your nested form?

```
<%= f.fields_for :addresses, Address.new do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.hidden_field :parent_kind, :value => 2 %>
  ...
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use it due to security concerns, here's another way that might help. You can try using an [association callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) like so:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :foreign_key => "parent_id", 
                       :conditions => ['parent_kind = ?', 2],
                       :before_add => Proc.new { |store,address| address.parent_kind = 2}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work, but still `bad people` could overwrite the hidden field before sending the post.